# jQuery bind mouseover/mouseout :after

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think I have a brain teaser here.

I want to bind mouseover and mouseout specifically to the :after tag of an element, without it bubbeling down the tree. The bind obviously works now, but it doesn't see :after as an independant element, which is the point of my problem.

html:

```
<div class="menuitem editable"></div>
```

CSS for after:

```
.menuitem:after {
  padding:2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  font-family: 'chevron';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "\f054";
  top: 45%;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  border-top-left-radius:3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.editable').bind('mouseover', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
$('.editable').bind('mouseout', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
$('.menuitem:after').bind('mouseover', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  after_color = $(this).css('background');
  alert(after_color);
  $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)');
});
$('.menuitem:after').bind('mouseout', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).css('background', after_color);
});
```

Please don't ask me why I'm doing in detail or change the html setup, cause it's for a stylebuilder and it is what it is.

Comment: The best I can think of is using css via `:hover:after` but that affects your `.menuitem`'s hover while styling the after. Not quite what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are not part of the DOM tree and cannot be accessed via JavaScript like elements that are part of the DOM. And hence they cannot be individually bound to events.

A round-about way would be to emulate the `:after` pseudo element with a real DOM element and then binding the events to that instead.

For ex:

```
<div class="menuitem editable">
    <div class="after">arrow</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menuitem { 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: visible;
}
.menuitem .after {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    ...
}
.menuitem.hovering .after {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.menuitem').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovering');
});
$('.menuitem').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovering');
});
```

And then...

```
$('.menuitem .after').on('mouseout', function() {
    // stuff ...
});
```

Comment: For additional insight, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460273/what-is-the-element-type-of-pseudo-elements

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that. Thank you for the conformation, I will look into your sollution. I might just have to do that to even make it work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
content: '<i class="some">...</i>';
```

then

```
$('.some').bind('mouseout', function(event) {
    //your function
});
```